# Make view controller rotate immediately base on device orientation

Tags: ios

I have 2 view controllers A and B. View controller A is portrait only and view controller B can rotate.

When the phone is landscape, I push view controller A and it's orientation is portrait -> good.

But when i push view controller B from view controller A (the phone is still landscape), view controller B's orientation is portrait, that is not what i want.
I have to rotate device to portrait then landscape to make view controller B rotate to landscape.

My question is, how can i make view controller B rotate immediately after push from A, in respect to device orientation?

Answer (score 0):

Use this it may be resolve your poblem

AppDelegate.m

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{

return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

}
```

ViewController

```
-(void) restrictRotation:(BOOL) restriction
{
AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
appDelegate.restrictRotation = restriction;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what is restrictRotation?

Answer (score 0):

To rotate device orientation use this code in your **viewWillAppear** and **viewWillDisAppear** according to need

```
 NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

And to rotate View use this code

```
[self shouldAutorotate];
[self supportedInterfaceOrientations];
```

And Define this method in **ViewController.m**

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
return YES;
}
```

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{

```
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;    
}
```

It will Help.Thankyou